# Service bus message GetBody does not include inherited properties

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I have a base class "Entity" and a derived class "Site" or "Group". Both are marked as serializable. I am sending them to the service bus and retrieving as follows. None of the inherited properties are set after reading, however; it's as if they are ignored during deserialization. Any way I can get these to work or do I need to write my own XML deserializer?

```
var queueEntity = new QueueEntity(e);  // e is Entity, Site
var brokered = new BrokeredMessage(queueEntity);
QueueContext.QueueClient.Send(brokered);
```

Worker role

```
var message = receivedMessage.GetBody<QueueEntity>();
var e = message.Entity; // this only has derived class property values set
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize it using existing serializers and pass into BrokeredMesdage as a Stream. On the receiving side do the other way around, serializing from a Stream into your object.